# object creation and form association with unique IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to implement a drag and drop UI based project builder using Gulp Modules. Currently, I have three containers (divs) for my project - the first one holds a representation of each Gulp Module as a div, the second container acts as a Task Pipeline that sets the source and destination for the Gulp Modules to work, and the last one is triggered when a Gulp Module is clicked, to configure various options.

The current problem I am having is with the drop functionality with each Gulp Module, based on the following code:

```
    //drop gulp module into each task 
    this.makeDroppable = function (element) {
        var droppedModule;
        $(element).droppable({
            accept: ".gulp-module",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var self = this;
                console.log("Before new ID: ", this);
                if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("classAdded")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("classAdded");
                    return;
                }
                droppedModule = $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("classAdded").attr("id", ("task-" + Date.now())));
                console.log("After new ID: ", this);
            }
        }).sortable();
    };
```

I am trying to associate the new ID for each module that is dropped with the form that is created through the Gulp Module Class, which is shown below:

```
    function GulpModule(jsonData) {

    this.name = jsonData.name;
    this.info = jsonData.info;
    this.gulpModuleId = ("module-" + Date.now());

    this.inputLabels = [];
    this.inputFields = [];

    this.optionsForm = "<h3>" + this.name + "</h3><form id='form-"
        + this.gulpModuleId + "' class='form' method='post'>";

    // Get and Set the name of the gulp module
    this.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };

    this.setName = function (newName) {
        this.name = ((newName.length > 0) ? (newName) : this.name);
    };


    // Get and Set the data for the gulp module
    this.getInfo = function () {
        return this.info;
    };

    // Create a drag event for the gulp module object
    this.moduleDragEvent = function (element) {
        $(element).draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });
    };

    // Create the HTML element for the gulp module object and add it to the DOM
    this.createElement = function () {
        var element = $("<div></div>")
            .attr("class", "gulp-module")
            .attr("id", this.gulpModuleId)
            .append($("<h5></h5>").text(this.name))
            .data("info", this.info)
            .data("form", this.createOptionsForm())
            .appendTo("#gulp-modules");
        this.moduleDragEvent(element);
    };

    // Create the form options for gulp modules that can be configured
    this.createOptionsForm = function () {
        var info = this.getInfo(),
            labelInfo = Object.keys(info.params),
            newInputObject,
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < labelInfo.length; i += 1) {
            this.inputLabels.push("<label for='" + labelInfo[i] + "'>" + labelInfo[i] + "</label>");
            newInputObject = new InputElement(info.params[labelInfo[i]]);
            this.inputFields.push(newInputObject.createInputElement());
            this.optionsForm += (this.inputLabels[i] + "<br>" + this.inputFields[i] + "<br><br>");
        }
        this.optionsForm += "</form>";
        // console.log(this.optionsForm);
        // $("#module-options").append(this.optionsForm);
    };
}
```

Outside of this class, I make an XMLHttpRequest for a JSON file that has the data for each module, and that is how I parse them - through a loop that makes a new instance of the Gulp Module and associates the relevant data with it.

When I drop it however, I need it to associate the new ID that is generated on drop with the new form, so that it points to that module's form. I don't even need to have a form associated initially; only when it is dropped, but the way I set it up made sense to me.

Is there an easier way to approach this, either through taking out the form building functionality from the GulpModule object, or through fixing the drop functionality?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!